# How to get user/creation date of Trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers

**Is there any way to get the creation date(time) of the trigger ?**

I tried the following query:

```
select CREATED from user_objects where object_name = '&MY_TRIGGER_NAME'
```

but i think, i get the last modification/run date, not the creation time.

And also, i want to get the user who created the trigger...if it is possible.

Comment: @Tejash gave you a very good explanation of 'when'.  The 'who' is what AUDIT is for.  If you were not AUDITing that action when it occurred, then you will not be able to determine the 'who'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2005.htm#i1583352), fields of the `USER_OBJECTS` is described as:

- `CREATED`: Timestamp for the creation of the object
- `LAST_DDL_TIME`: Timestamp for the last modification of the object resulting from a DDL statement (including grants and revokes)

Let's do one exercise:

Checking in the `USER_OBJECTS` table for trigger `TRG_T`

```
SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME,
  2         OBJECT_TYPE,
  3         CREATED,
  4         LAST_DDL_TIME
  5    FROM USER_OBJECTS
  6   WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'TRG_T';

no rows selected
```

Now, Let's create the trigger `TRG_T`

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_T BEFORE
  2  INSERT ON T
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5  NULL;
  6  END;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Let's check in the `USER_OBJECTS`

```
SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME,
  2         OBJECT_TYPE,
  3         CREATED,
  4         LAST_DDL_TIME
  5    FROM USER_OBJECTS
  6   WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'TRG_T';

OBJECT_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE     CREATED              LAST_DDL_TIME
--------------- --------------- -------------------- --------------------
TRG_T           TRIGGER         02-jul-2020 12:41:29 02-jul-2020 12:41:29
```

Currently, `CREATED` and `LAST_DDL_TIME` are the same because the last DDL operation on the trigger is when we created it.

Let's modify the trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_T BEFORE
  2  INSERT ON T
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  BEGIN
  5  NULL; -- do some changes
  6  NULL; -- CHANGED THIS
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.
```

Now, let's again check in the `USER_OBJECTS`:

```
SQL> SELECT OBJECT_NAME,
  2         OBJECT_TYPE,
  3         CREATED,
  4         LAST_DDL_TIME
  5    FROM USER_OBJECTS
  6   WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'TRG_T';

OBJECT_NAME     OBJECT_TYPE     CREATED              LAST_DDL_TIME
--------------- --------------- -------------------- --------------------
TRG_T           TRIGGER         02-jul-2020 12:41:29 02-jul-2020 12:42:05
```

See the `CREATED` and `LAST_DDL_TIME` is different here

Answer (score 0):

`CREATED` is the

> timestamp for the creation of the object

in USER_OBJECTS/ALL_OBJECTS/DBA_OBJECTS and not the last modified date  which is`LAST_DDL_TIME`.

To get trigger owner, you need to use `OWNER` column in ALL_TRIGGERS/DBA_TRIGGERS because USER_TRIGGERS displays only your *own* triggers without any OWNER column.

Answer (score -2):

there is a field called "created" in user_objects view which tells the creation time of the object. There is another column called last_ddl_time which would show the time of the last creation of the DDL

As for the user who created the object i am not sure its tracked unless you have got a logon trigger that logs this information i believe